# apt-cache - show future commands

Tags: apt

Is there a way to find out which commands will be available, once a package has been installed via `apt-get`?

Let's say I would like to run `apt-get -y net-tools`.

```
Host> apt-cache show net-tools
Package: net-tools
Version: 1.60-24.2
Installed-Size: 916
Maintainer: net-tools Team <pkg-net-tools-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Replaces: ja-trans (<= 0.8-2), netbase (<< 4.00)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
Conflicts: ja-trans (<= 0.8-2)
Description-en: The NET-3 networking toolkit
 This package includes the important tools for controlling the network
 subsystem of the Linux kernel.  This includes arp, ifconfig, netstat,
 rarp, nameif and route.  Additionally, this package contains utilities
 relating to particular network hardware types (plipconfig, slattach,
 mii-tool) and advanced aspects of IP configuration (iptunnel, ipmaddr).
 .
 In the upstream package 'hostname' and friends are included. Those are
 not installed by this package, since there is a special "hostname*.deb".
Homepage: http://net-tools.berlios.de/
Description-md5: 003fb6a11fdb767fff574478588a3ca8
Tag: admin::configuring, implemented-in::c, interface::commandline,
 network::configuration, network::routing, network::vpn, protocol::ipv6,
 role::program, scope::utility, use::routing
Section: net
Priority: important
Filename: pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60-24.2_amd64.deb
Size: 346084
MD5sum: 7ef2fa3c53ba45adf9b3c369ef5ba458
SHA1: f8fa10c12f3309c69ed2a010e4824b6c41957c20
SHA256: a27cb96bc41b9349f6ab0a102cf8ed9210a129b2a67ca2a108675235d3600aaa

Host>
```

Does `apt-cache show net-tools` already reveal everyting (arp, ifconfig, netstat, rarp, nameif, route, plipconfig, slattach, mii-tool, iptunnel, ipmaddr)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-cache` has no way to do this. However, `apt-file` will do what you're asking. Manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/apt-file.1.html

You can run `apt-file list net-tools` to list files installed by net-tools, even if net-tools isn't installed.

`apt-file` does make use of a cache for this info, which you'll need to periodically update using `apt-file update`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apt-file` to list all the files in a package even though you haven't downloaded it yet. Then filter it through grep.

```
$ apt-file list net-tools | grep bin
net-tools: /bin/netstat
net-tools: /sbin/ifconfig
net-tools: /sbin/ipmaddr
net-tools: /sbin/iptunnel
net-tools: /sbin/mii-tool
net-tools: /sbin/nameif
net-tools: /sbin/plipconfig
net-tools: /sbin/rarp
net-tools: /sbin/route
net-tools: /sbin/slattach
net-tools: /usr/sbin/arp
```